# How to get monthly cost data from Azure using Python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python, azure-management-api, azure-billing-api, azure-cost-calculation

I'm trying to get monthly cost data from Azure using Azure SDK for Python, but Microsoft Documentation seems very confusing and outdated, without examples. I need to create a monthly evolution chart outside Azure Portal.

What is the right way to retrieve this information about monthly costs from Azure?

I already tried to use **BillingManagementClient** class, **get_for_billing_period_by_billing_account** method from **ConsumptionManagementClient.balances**, and now I'm trying to use **usage_details.list** method from **ConsumptionManagementClient**, but I'm receiving a strange duplicated data:

```
consumption_client = ConsumptionManagementClient(self.credential, self.subscription_id)
start_date = "2022-11-19T00:00:00.0000000Z"
end_date = "2022-11-20T00:00:00.0000000Z"
filters = f"properties/usageStart eq '{start_date}' and properties/usageEnd eq '{end_date}'"
consumption_list = consumption_client.usage_details.list(f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}", None, filters)

for consumption_data in consumption_list:
    print(f"date: {consumption_data.date} \nstart_date: {consumption_data.billing_period_start_date} \nend_date: {consumption_data.billing_period_end_date}\ncost: {consumption_data.cost} \n")
```

Script output:

> date: 2022-11-20 00:00:00+00:00
> start_date: 2022-11-11 00:00:00+00:00
> end_date: 2022-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
> cost: 0.658392
>
> date: 2022-11-19 00:00:00+00:00
> start_date: 2022-11-11 00:00:00+00:00
> end_date: 2022-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
> cost: 0.658392
>
> date: 2022-11-19 00:00:00+00:00
> start_date: 2022-11-11 00:00:00+00:00
> end_date: 2022-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
> cost: 0.67425593616
>
> date: 2022-11-20 00:00:00+00:00
> start_date: 2022-11-11 00:00:00+00:00
> end_date: 2022-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
> cost: 0.67425593616

Answer (score 0):

It's a mess.

I suggest you to [connect Power BI to Azure Cost Management](https://www.jeeja.biz/2022/11/11/azure-finops-connect-power-bi-to-azure-cost-management/) instead as this will give you an out-of-the-box solution.